# Why isn't the link opening in iframe when I click a button?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a HTML page with a dropdown list and when I select an option, an iframe is opening containing another HTML page. Inside the second HTML page I have button and when I click the button I want to open a link (inside the iframe). When I run only the second page it's working, but when I run the first page (with the dropdown list) it's not working anymore.

Does anyone knows why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Here is an example of code for the first page:

```js
function Ex(form) {
            var myindex = Example.drop.selectedIndex
            if (Example.drop.options[myindex] != "0") {
                window.open(Example.drop.options[myindex].value, target = "iframe1");
            }
        }
```

```html
<form name="Example">
        <select name="drop" onchange="Ex(this.Example)">
            <option value="about:blank">Select something...</option>
            <option value="Page1.html">Page1</option>
            <option value="Page2.html">Page2</option>
            <option value="Page3.html">Page3</option>
            
        </select>


        <iframe id="iframe1" name="iframe1" src="about:blank" align="top" height="900" width="1000" style="border:none; "></iframe>
    </form>
```

And here is an example of code for one of the pages that open inside the iframe:

```html
<img src="http://focusdesignz.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/picture_1436728897.jpg"/>

<input type="button" onclick="location.href='http://www.google.ro'" value="Some Button"/>
```

Comment: Is it opening at all? It might be because Google doesn't allow you to open in an iframe, it breaks out of it?

Comment: @putvande It works now. It was Google's fault. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works if **not** in a iframe.

In a iframe, error message : **[Error] Refused to display 'https://www.google.ro/?gws_rd=ssl' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'. (button.html, line 3)**.

Google.ro seems to refuse being iframed.

If you use another URL than Google.ro, get sure your Cross-Domain policy is ok. The URL must agree with being displayed in an iFrame.

Comment: I found out that it works with my pages. I am opening HTML pages, so it doesn't have any restrictions. Anyway your answer is pretty good.